# Android Studio - Gradle builds all flavors of library instead of only current one

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My app consists of main module `mobile` and library module `core`. Each of them has two build flavors: `flavor1` and `flavor2`.

**Library build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {        
    ....
    publishNonDefault true
    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {}
        flavor2 {}
    }
}
```

**Project build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    ....
    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {}
        flavor2 {}
    }
}

configurations {
    flavor1DebugCompile
    flavor2DebugCompile
    flavor1ReleaseCompile
    flavor2ReleaseCompile
}

dependencies {
    ....
    flavor1DebugCompile project(path: ':core', configuration: 'flavor1Debug')
    flavor2DebugCompile project(path: ':core', configuration: 'flavor2Debug')
    flavor1ReleaseCompile project(path: ':core', configuration: 'flavor1Release')
    flavor2ReleaseCompile project(path: ':core', configuration: 'flavor2Release')
}
```

Now everything works and compiles, but I noticed something strange in how Gradle builds the library:

If I assemble library, by doing `gradlew :core:assembleFlavor1Debug` - it will only compile code for `flavor1` (I see task `core:compileFlavor1DebugJavaWithJavac` being executed).

However when I try to build the project itself (or just pressing the 'Run' button) - `gradlew :mobile:assembleFlavor1Debug` I see in output, that library was built for both build flavors, calling `core:compileFlavor1DebugJavaWithJavac` and `core:compileFlavor2DebugJavaWithJavac`, even thought I specifically selected to build `flavor1` only!

Now, this looks really strange to me, why would it build all flavors instead of the required flavor only? Is it a bug in Gradle or just the way it handles libraries?